# How do you save changes to navigation properties using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am trying to add a composite key in a many-to-many table using entity framework, but it is not adding the key.

This is our service method which adds an item to a property

Property is a table, 
Item is table, 
PropertyItem is the table involved in the many-to-many relationship.

EF does not generate an entity for PropertyItem, so i am trying to add items through the property entity. Changing the navigation property for items in the property does not save the changes.

I have tried Lazy Loading but it does not make a difference

```
public void addPropertyItem(int propertyId, int itemId)
    {
        ErrorHandler errorHandler = new ErrorHandler();
        try
        {
            Item item = itemRepo.getSingle(i => i.itemId.Equals(itemId));
            if (item == null)
            {
                errorHandler.addException("Item does not exist.");
            }
            Property property = propertyRepo.getSingle(p => p.propertyId.Equals(propertyId), p => p.Items);
            if (property == null)
            {
                errorHandler.addException("Property does not exist.");
            }

            if (!errorHandler.hasErrors())
            {
                foreach (Item i in property.Items)
                {
                    if (i.itemId == item.itemId)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }

                property.Items.Add(item);

                propertyRepo.update(property);
            }
```

The data is retrieved using the following code:

```
public virtual T getSingle(Func<T, bool> where,
         params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)
    {
        T item = null;
        using (var context = new PropertyManagementDBEntities())
        {
            IQueryable<T> dbQuery = context.Set<T>();

            //Apply eager loading
            foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
                dbQuery = dbQuery.Include<T, object>(navigationProperty);

            item = dbQuery
                .FirstOrDefault(where); //Apply where clause
        }
        return item;
    }
```

This is the update on the DAL side.

```
public virtual void update(params T[] items)
    {
        using (var context = new PropertyManagementDBEntities())
        {
            foreach (T item in items)
            {
                context.Entry(item).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks,

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want, you need to have a DbContext to track the changes, i.e., you need to implement a method like this:

```
using (var context = new PropertyManagementDBEntities())
{
    // Implement here code that
    // 1. Get the Property (or properties)
    // 2. Get the Item (or items)
    // 3. Adds the Item (or items) to the Property (or proerties)
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

In this way the DbContext is tracking changes (i.e. is aware of what's going on), so that it knows about the new relation (it does "relationship fix-up"), and, when invoking `SaveChanges` it saves the new relationships.

If there is no DbContext tracking the changes, the relationship changes are not detected, so the changes are not applied to the DB.

So you need to implement this method in one of your repos.

There is other option which is executing directly a SQL `INSERT` command with the corresponding keys, i.e. execute an `INSERT INTO PropertyItem( <col names>) VALUES (<col values parameters>)`. To do so, you need to use the [DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679456%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) which accepts the query, and the corrresponding parameters. If you do it this way, the DbContext will not know inmediately about the relationship changes, but, as you're using short lived DbContexts, that's not a problem for you.